# Problema de CORS usando localhost y una api

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

llevo unos días dándole vueltas a un problema que me está apareciendo al intentar acceder a los datos de una api que tengo en mi proyecto y a la que intento acceder desde localhost. El problema tiene que ver con la CORS policy, que no me deja acceder a la url porque no la considera segura. En principio esto es fácil de solucionar añadiendo un header con 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' pero no sirve de nada puesto que me sigue dando error. También intenté instalar 'nelmio/cors-bundle' que hace esto automáticamente pero tampoco sirvió de nada.

He intentado meter esa cabecera de todas las formas y ninguna funciona. Si uso una api de fuera como por ejemplo rickandmortyapi.com no me da problemas porque sí que la considera segura. Todas las soluciones que he visto por internet han fallado y sinceramente ya no sé qué hacer, estoy iniciándome en JS y no puedo avanzar si no puedo acceder a la api.

Este es el fetch que trae la información de la api, lo he puesto lo más simple posible.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/Alumnos/api')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));})
```

Este es el código que accede a los datos de alumnos.

```
#[Route('/Alumnos/api/', name: 'app_Alumnos_api_getAll', methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'])]
public function getAlumnos(AlumnosRepository $Alumnosrep): JsonResponse
{
    $Alumnoss = $Alumnosrep->findAll();

    if ($Alumnosrep) {
        foreach ($Alumnoss as $Alumnos) {
            $datos[] = $Alumnosrep->toArray($Alumnos);
        }
    } else {
        "No hay alumnos creados";
    }
    
    return $this->json($datos, $status = 200);
}
```

He probado ya a meter el header en toda la api, en el ejemplo concreto de get, en index, con nelmio. No sé qué más probar.

Añadirle la característica {no-cors} al fetch no funcionaría porque evitaría el problema y a la vez evitaría el acceso a esos datos.

Este es el error que salta siempre. Incluso cambiando el fetch y usando jquery o el ajax más básico.

[image: Error que salta cada vez que intento acceder a la api que tengo en localhost]

Comment: Prueba a quitar la **s** de `https://localhost` en tu navegador al cargar la página

Comment: Quitarla no, pero añadirla al fetch sí. Dios, vaya forma de perder el tiempo cuando el problema era una simple letra. Gracias